# How can we redirect to previous page after login in cibonfire?

Tags: codeigniter

How can we redirect to previous page after login in cibonfire?

If some module require login to view, than the code there will check for login and if it is not logged in, it will redirect to login page. After login we want to get back to same module. How can we do so.

Thanks

Comment: redirect("view_file_name");

Answer (score 4):

Before your checking ,A user is already loged in ,Add

```
   $this->session->set_userdata('page_url',  current_url());
```

Add in your login function ,After checking the login data.

```
if($this->session->userdata('page_url'))
       redirect($this->session->userdata('page_url'));
else
      redirect('default home page');
```

Comment: Thnks @Shin..Helpful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your controller function add this line

```
redirect('your_view_here', $any_variables_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use sessions for logging in and for navegation tasks like that, because it just makes life a lot simpler. In my controller functions I drop in a line of code like the following:

```
$this->load_segs(func_get_args(), strtolower(__CLASS__).'/'.__FUNCTION__);
```

Here's the load segements function:

```
function load_segs($params, $src){
    if ( ! is_array($params) || ! isset($src)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    foreach ($params as $key => $value){
        //only include values that don't need encoding
        if ($value != urlencode($value)){
            break;
        }
        $src .= '/'.htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('return', $src);
    return $src;
}
```

You can retrieve the information as follows:

```
$return = html_entity_decode($this->session->userdata('return'));
redirect($return);
```